# retrieving JSON object using a html link and displaying the json data on a html page

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to retrieve a JSON object when the user clicks the html link. i want to retrieve it by it's ID and display everything in the object on the html page. I am also using session storage..... I want the user to be taken to the info.html page after they follow the html link.

my html code so far:

```
<div class="col">
    <!-- team-img -->
    <div class="team-block">
        <div class="team-content">
            <h4 class="text-white mb0">Chocolate Cake </h4>
            <p class="team-meta">Large</p>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">
                <h4 class="mb0 text-white"> Chocolate Cake </h4>
                <p class="mb30 team-meta"> Large </p>
                <p>Large Chocolate cake. 15 servings.</p>
                <p><a href="info.html" id="1">Further info</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The ID of the cake is "1" In the JSON file. I want all the details of the cake to be displayed when the user clicks the link. I want the user to be taken to info.html. The data of the cake which is stored in the JSON should be displayed there. The problem is with this line:

```
<p><a href="info.html" id="1">Further info</a></p>
```

My JSON file is called cakes.json

below is my .js file

```
var ajax=function(url,success)
{
    var ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    var handleResponse=function()
    {
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState===4)
        {
            if(ajaxRequest.status===200)
            {
                var data=JSON.parse(ajaxRequest.responseText);
                success(data); //this will call populateList
            }
        }
    }
    ajaxRequest.addEventListener("readystatechange",handleResponse,false); 
    ajaxRequest.open('GET', url, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null);
}

var navList;
var contentDiv;

function createHandler(car)
{
    return function(){
        sessionStorage.setItem("cake",JSON.stringify(cake));
    }
}

function populateList(cakes)
{
    navList=document.getElementById("nav");
    contentDiv=document.getElementById("content");

    cakes.forEach(function(cake){
        var newLi=document.createElement("ul");
        var newLink=document.createElement("a");
        newLink.innerHTML=cake.name;
        newLink.setAttribute("href","info.html");
        newLink.addEventListener("click", createHandler(cake), false)
        newLi.appendChild(newLink);
        navList.appendChild(newLi);
    })
}

function init(){
    ajax("data/cakes.json",populateList);
}

init();
```

JSON file:

```
[
        {
        "id":1,
        "cake":"chocolate cake",
        "servings":"15",
        "size":"10",
        "code":"ed39"   
    },
```

]

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should modify the href you are sending in `a` tag to contain `info.html?id=1` (query parameters) and in your script you should retrieve this id to get the required json value.

Comment: You should have a `function` that parses the `json` and retrieve the info for the desired `id`, if you can put the `json` here I can help you with that

Comment: There's no `cake` when `sessionStorage.setItem("cake",JSON.stringify(cake))` is executed

Comment: Can you please change my code and show me how its done? As i have tried this before but failed.

Comment: I have added my JSON file Sabbin

Comment: I'll do a fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done an example of how this can be done using your structure of `array` containing multiple `objects`. Also I've modified your `html` added `data-id` parameter instead of `id` usually you don't save the `id` of an object in the `id` of html element(not best practice), you can use the `data-` params, there is also a function in `jQuery` that reads these parametes `$(selector).data('identifier')`

```js
var json = [{
  "id": 1,
  "cake": "chocolate cake",
  "servings": "15",
  "size": "10",
  "code": "ed39"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "cake": "vanilla cake",
  "servings": "15",
  "size": "10",
  "code": "ed39"
}];

$(document).on('click', '.cakeDetailsButton', function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id'),
    details = getDetailsById(id), //Here all the details for the cake
    resultDiv = $('.result');
  resultDiv.text('');
  $.each(details, function(key, value) {
    resultDiv.append(key + ' -- ' + value + '<br/>') // Here you can do whatever with the details
  })
});

function getDetailsById(id) {
  for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    if (json[i].id == id) {
      return json[i];
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><a class="cakeDetailsButton" href="#" data-id="1">Further info 1</a></p>
<p><a class="cakeDetailsButton" href="#" data-id="2">Further info 2</a></p>
<div class="result">

</div>
```

**EDIT - Update**

In order to add your `json` in the `localStorage` in order to access it from anywhere update the following

> .js file

```
function populateList(cakes)
{
    localStorage.setItem('cakesJson', cakes); //This adds an object to the localStorage with the key cakesJson and value the cakes object
    navList=document.getElementById("nav");
    contentDiv=document.getElementById("content");

    cakes.forEach(function(cake){
        var newLi=document.createElement("ul");
        var newLink=document.createElement("a");
        newLink.innerHTML=cake.name;
        newLink.setAttribute("href","info.html");
        newLink.addEventListener("click", createHandler(cake), false)
        newLi.appendChild(newLink);
        navList.appendChild(newLi);
    })
}
```

Also then in the code provided by me above you should change the following

```
function getDetailsById(id) {
  var json = localStorage.getItem("cakesJson"); // Here you retrieve the values stored in the localStorage
  for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    if (json[i].id == id) {
      return json[i];
    }
  }
}
```

The event listener remains the same as in the snippet

```
$(document).on('click', '.cakeDetailsButton', function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id'),
    details = getDetailsById(id), //Here all the details for the cake
    resultDiv = $('.result');
  resultDiv.text('');
  $.each(details, function(key, value) {
    resultDiv.append(key + ' -- ' + value + '<br/>') // Here you can do whatever with the details
  })
});
```